# Why my divs moves by different value than they should be in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pixel

For my studies I'm doing few tasks in HTML, CSS, JS and JQuery too.

The main task is to move big(red) box and small(blue) box.

It should work like this: user checks upper(bigbox) or lower(smallbox) radio to move certain box by number of pixels(working with position:absolute) that he writes in text input(initialy 30px).

The problem is that boxes should move exactly by 30px BUT actually as you can see in console it moves by 39px - it happens with any input value - boxes move by different values than they should and with really low "speed" for example 5px right and left button BOTH moves box to the right and top and down button moves box to the bottom and even outside the box.

I'm working with JS for one week only so I'am really new to it and any help will be highly appreciated! If my code is clumsy - Sorry I don't know how good web code should look like yet, I'm still working on it!

**UPDATE**:DaniP answered me in the comment section. The problem I was dealing with was that I forgot that actual elements had margins that were also added to absolute position. So the ultimate solution is to set body margins to 0 and everything is working perfectly.

```js
function parseSpeed() {
    var speed = $('#speed').val();
    if (isNaN(speed)) {
        speed = 0;
    } else {
        speed = parseInt(speed, 10);
    }
    return speed;
}
function moveIfPossible(direction) {
    var activeBox = document.getElementById(swapBoxesIfNeeded());
    var x = activeBox.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var y = activeBox.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(activeBox.id + ": x:" + x + ",y:" + y);
    var speed = parseSpeed();
    var boxlimit = 400;
    if(activeBox.id === "smallbox"){
        boxlimit = 370;
    }else{
        boxlimit = 340;
    }
    switch (direction) {
        case 0:
            if (x - speed >= 0) {
                activeBox.style.left = (x - speed) + "px";
            } else {
                activeBox.style.left = 0 + "px";
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (x + speed <= boxlimit) {
                activeBox.style.left = (x + speed) + "px";
            } else {
                activeBox.style.left = boxlimit + "px";
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (y - speed >= 0) {
                activeBox.style.top = (y - speed) + "px";
            } else {
                activeBox.style.top = 0 + "px";
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (y + speed <= boxlimit) {
                activeBox.style.top = (y + speed) + "px";
            } else {
                activeBox.style.top = boxlimit + "px";
            }
            break;
    }
}

function swapBoxesIfNeeded() {
    if (document.getElementById("small").checked) {
        return "smallbox";
    } else if (document.getElementById("big").checked) {
        return "bigbox";
    }
}

function moveBoxUp() {
    moveIfPossible(2);
}

function moveBoxDown() {
    moveIfPossible(3);
}

function moveBoxLeft() {
    moveIfPossible(0);
}

function moveBoxRight() {
    moveIfPossible(1);
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

#game_window {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

#control_panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}

#stats {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

#speed {
    width: 20px;
}

#smallbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid blue 1px;
}

#bigbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: solid red 1px;
}

#buttons {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#up {
    background: lightgray url("images/arrow-up-bold.png") no-repeat center;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

#down {
    background: lightgray url("images/arrow-down-bold.png") no-repeat center;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

#left {
    background: lightgray url("images/arrow-left-bold.png") no-repeat center;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

#right {
    background: lightgray url("images/arrow-right-bold.png") no-repeat center;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zadanie 6</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Iwb,Lista 2,Zadanie 6"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Rozwiązanie listy 2 z BDAMI"/>
    <meta name="author" content="213"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="zad6.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script src="zad6.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="game_window">
        <div id="smallbox"></div>
        <div id="bigbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="control_panel">
        <div id="stats">
            <input type="radio" id="big" name="radio" checked title="radio1"/>Duże pudełko<br/>
            <input type="radio" id="small" name="radio" title="radio2"/>Małe pudełko<br/>
            <input type="text" id="speed" name="text" title="text1" size="2" maxlength="2" value="30"/>Szybkość(px)
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="up" title="up" onclick="moveBoxUp();"><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="left" title="left" onclick="moveBoxLeft();">
                <input type="button" id="down" title="down" onclick="moveBoxDown();">
                <input type="button" id="right" title="right" onclick="moveBoxRight();">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without inspecting a lot your code I guess you are taking the offset of the element, that is relative to the window and by default the body has a `margin of 8px` and plus the `1px of the border on the container` there you have that "9px" offset extra

Comment: @DaniP Sounds reasonable. That would also explain why the position in the top-left corner is at (9, 9).

Comment: @DaniP Thanks, that explains the first issue! Any toughts why when i set speed to 5 px both right and left moves the box to the right?

Comment: The same explanation .... because the `left`you are modifying is relative to the contianer but the offset you are getting is relative to the window. That way the calculate for the if statements isn't accurate. Just set body margin to 0 and you will see

Comment: @DaniP Wow thanks - it did work exactly as intended. Thanks for all the help and I guess I have to read some more about it.

Comment: Glad tohelp u mate